# What is the below code

Tags: html, fckeditor

I am getting an issue wherein I am using FCKEditor, and once I type in something, in the source of FCKEditor, something like below is getting iserted automatically.

```
<input type="hidden" id="gwProxy" /><!--Session data--><input type="hidden" id="jsProxy" />
<div id="refHTML">&nbsp;</div>
```

Some hidden tag is getting inserted, which isnot getting diplayed here in my question.
Can anyone tell me about this.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: changed the tags to reflect this.. seems more like a FCKEditor question

Comment: I know its not PHP, by mistake I typed in PHP

Comment: The letters are *right next to each other*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a FCKEditor/CKEditor and Firefox specific issue described [here](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=13886) in conjunction with the browser highlighter add-on.

According to the post, disabling that add-on will fix the problem.

See [suspicious JS appearing in webpages from Browser Highlighter Add on](https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/forum/1/381225)